# compiler optimization: move variable from stack to register

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, language-lawyer, compiler-optimization

Here is the code:

```cpp
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstddef>

uint64_t uint5korr(const std::byte *p)
{
  uint64_t result= 0;
  std::memcpy(&result, p, 5);
  return result;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/vULPAZ

clang here optimizes `result` to a register while gcc doesn't.
I suspect this can be somehow related to the fact I'm taking an address of a variable as one can not take the address of a register.

Is this simply a missing optimization in gcc or maybe clang violates standard somehow?

Comment: as the complier has full knowledge on what is done with the pointer on result, he can ensure that the optimization is valid so i think this falls under as if rule

Comment: It's obvious without benchmarking that putting a variable on stack here is slower. Basically, I want this code to be optimized by gcc and I wanna know will this be correct or not.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are no requirements in the standard about how they optimize, as long as they work right. But I don't have anything to cite to back me up. Looking.

Comment: Unless this code is being run in a *very* tight loop hundreds of thousands of times per second, I doubt you will ever be able to measure any meaningful performance difference. So, why really care?

Comment: it's better to click the clone compiler button so that we can compare the versions in the same window

Comment: I'm writing a patch which fixes incorrect aliasing while decoding `int`s from a byte stream. I used `memcpy()` and the new (correct) version of function is slower. Reviewer asked me about performance. And I need to explain him why the new code is slower. That's why I'm care. I agree performance doesn't matter in my case, though.

Comment: Why are you copying only 5 bytes here? I didn't thoroughly check this with the standard yet, but it would seem to me that this could very well be undefined behavior. `std::uint64_t` is a trivially-copyable type, but you're not copying the whole object representation here…

Comment: Yes that's certainly related, if you copy 8 bytes the memcpy gets completely elided away in both gcc and clang. But given the function name I assume that's some dumb protocol using 5 byte integers.

Comment: Yes, this is from serialization which uses 5-byte integers :)

Comment: I'm not copying from `std::uint64_t`. I'm copy into it after it was previously initialized. Does it change your point about possible standard violation?

Comment: I already thought that you're doing serialization/deserialization here. And I may be wrong, but I can't seem to find anything in the standard that would allow you to copy only a few bytes from and back into an `std::uint64_t`, and access the resulting value. I also can't really seem to find anything that would explicitly not allow it though…

Comment: Did you compare performance of the memcpy directly into the destination, rather than into a register 'temporary'?  i.e.  "void  "uint5korr(const std::byte*, uint64_t&)"

Comment: I didn't try because I can not change signature of my function.

Comment: I suspect the behavior here is "unspecified", not "undefined", because of the restrictions on value representations of integral types. But note in particular, you *will* get different behavior on little-endian, big-endian, and other-endian architectures.

Comment: This code is for AMD64 so endianness is not an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this optimization is legitimate.  5 bytes (not 8) are read from the correct address; there’s no need to store them again just to read them for the `return`, address taken or no.  I share Michael Kenzel’s skepticism that this has defined behavior, but that can only cement the validity of the optimization.

Comment: `uint64_t` is guaranteed to be a fixed-width 64-bit type with no padding bits.  Its object-representation is pure binary place-value.  Writing the low 5 bytes of its object representation is not UB, but endianness is implementation-dependent.  i.e. on any given implementation, it has to work consistently for all callers.

Answer (score 1):

Not a [language-lawyer](/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) answer.

While the optimization itself is really seems to be missing in GCC, but the usage of a partial `memcpy`ed value IIUC is an undefined behaviour. I would file a bug to GCC to get a clear response on the subject.

A perfectly optimized by GCC/Clang/MSVC way to load 40bit width integer:

```
std::uint64_t load_u40(const std::byte *p)
{
  std::uint8_t lo = 0;
  std::memcpy(&lo, p, 1);
  std::uint32_t hi = 0;
  std::memcpy(&hi, p + 1, 4);
  return (static_cast<std::uint64_t>(hi) << 8) | lo;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/4Kk9IM

Comment: How is this a GCC bug?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Here is my ticket on this topic in GCC bug tracker https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=89804

Comment: @aschepler missing optimization opportunity/suboptimal code generation is considered a bug. https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?keywords=missed-optimization

Comment: It's not UB to write part of an object-representation.  Endianness is implementation-defined; code that depends on it might not be portable, but it's not UB.  Also, `uint64_t` is a fixed-width type that's guaranteed to have no padding bits or trap representations; this wouldn't be UB with `unsigned long` either but it could maybe be slightly more weird than you expect if you ever use the value.  Note that your version is also endian-sensitive.

Comment: @PeterCordes I didn't say that it is UB to write to a part of an object, but reading the object after that is not defined by the standard. The [\[basic.types\]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#2) covers only copying the whole object (including padding). One can say that it is covered by [\[basic.types\]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#4), but I'm not convinced, and implementation-defined behavior is not that good because it may vary from compiler to compiler. The endian-sensitivity was questioned in the comments and marked as not a problem by the author.

Comment: UB makes it not safely usable on *any* specific implementation.  Implementation-defined means you can use it after testing to see what it does on the one implementation you care about, if writing non-portable code.  (e.g. embedded, or a standard library implementation.)  Vastly different.  I'm pretty sure it's well-defined (other than endianness) for `uint64_t`, which is guaranteed to have no padding bits.  It's an optional type that implementations don't have to define if they don't have a type that works that way.  Pretty sure the point is guarantee the object-representation layout.